# Unable to make axis logarithmic in 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to make a 3D plot using `matplotlib` inside `jupyter-notebook`.
I am using a dataset from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data?select=test.csv).

The schema is the following

| LotArea | SalePrice | YrSold | PoolArea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8450 | 208500 | 2008 | 0 |
| 9600 | 181500 | 2007 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

When I plot with linear axes, everything is OK:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 15))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

area_data = dataset_chosen["LotArea"]
price_data = dataset_chosen["SalePrice"]
year_data = dataset_chosen["YrSold"]

cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")

ax.scatter3D(xs=area_data, ys=price_data, zs=year_data, c=dataset_chosen["PoolArea"])

#ax.set_xscale("log")

ax.set_xlabel("Area")
ax.set_ylabel("Price")
ax.set_zlabel("Year")

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with all linear scales.]
And when I try to make `x` scale logarithmic (uncomment `#ax.set_xscale("log")`), the plot does not look like a plot.
[image]

How to make X scale logarithmic?

Comment: It is already logarithmic. You see that data outliers on the right, so first you have delete this outliers

Comment: @sedub01 No, it is not. Matplotlib makes axes linear by default. About outliers: I don't need to remove them and did not ask about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209#issuecomment-138667884), there is a discussion on the same. This is a limitation/bug within 3d plots. As mentioned there, there is a workaround... basically, you need to manually do that scaling. Below is the updated code to do that. Hope this is what you are looking for... Note I used log10 as the numbers align up nicely.

```
dataset_chosen=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 15))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

area_data = np.log10(dataset_chosen["LotArea"])  ## Changed to LOG-10
price_data = dataset_chosen["SalePrice"]
year_data = dataset_chosen["YrSold"]

cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")

ax.scatter3D(xs=area_data, ys=price_data, zs=year_data, c=dataset_chosen["PoolArea"])

## Set the xticks and xticklables to what you want it to be...
xticks=[100,1000,10000,100000]
ax.set_xticks(np.log10(xticks))
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks)

#ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel("Area")
ax.set_ylabel("Price")
ax.set_zlabel("Year")

plt.show()
```

[image]